# Contract state does not change after sendTransaction

Tags: contract-development, contract-invocation

I created a very simple contract. Deployment is finished but it does not work as my expectation. Can you help me to fix it?

My expectation is changing "num" value after "add(int)" transaction.

The contract is followings.

**Tx**

https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x74426948905cd6e70e8b9d64a660b3c179b7c8a224ca5cd0234842768eb501db

**Raw Code**

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;
contract Addition {
  int num = 0;
  function add(int a){
    num += a;
  }
  function get() returns(int){
    return num;
  }
}
```

Although I did sendTransaction with "add(1)" data, the get value does not change.

The sendTransaction is below

**Tx**

https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x26db79c7c3c65992f17f4f62d5d191705933e785dff54db6d27e6f3a92d7117e

What I did:

(1) sendRawTransaction (create a contract)

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://xxxx:xxxx"));

var Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx');
var privateKey = new Buffer('xxxx', 'hex')

var rawTx = {
  nonce: '0x00',
  gasPrice: '0x10D1F',
  gasLimit: '0x10D1F',
  to: '0x692a70d2e424a56d2c6c27aa97d1a86395877b3a',
  data: '606060405260008055341561001357600080fd5b5b60d6806100226000396000f30060606040526000357c0100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000900463ffffffff1680636d4ce63c14604757806387db03b714606d575b600080fd5b3415605157600080fd5b6057608d565b6040518082815260200191505060405180910390f35b3415607757600080fd5b608b60048080359060200190919050506097565b005b6000805490505b90565b8060008082825401925050819055505b505600a165627a7a723058207e968ad53b91047ab71334a49530112b3725aaa27d9c6d3860da0bcf09c5c16d0029'
}

var tx = new Tx(rawTx);
tx.sign(privateKey);

var serializedTx = tx.serialize();

console.log('0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex'));

web3.eth.sendRawTransaction(serializedTx.toString('hex'), function(err, hash) {
  if (!err) {
    console.log(hash);
  } else {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

(2) sendRawTransaction (execute add() method)

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://xxxx:xxxx"));

var Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx');
var privateKey = new Buffer('xxxx', 'hex')

var rawTx = {
  nonce: '0x03',
  gasPrice: '0x53d9',
  gasLimit: '0x53d9',
  to: '0x692a70d2e424a56d2c6c27aa97d1a86395877b3a',
  data: '0x87db03b70000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001' // add(int256) with param 1
}

var tx = new Tx(rawTx);
tx.sign(privateKey);

var serializedTx = tx.serialize();

console.log('0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex')); // 0xf885038253d98253d994692a70d2e424a56d2c6c27aa97d1a86395877b3a80a487db03b700000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011ba0ec6de7c9c1f31dc95014156479925b2ebd933b715f2bb4450f5d74992d7b3423a016f6a7c6e1885412400a622f82ffa033936c06755896096c7638936c065571c1

web3.eth.sendRawTransaction('0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex'), function(err, hash) {
  if (!err) {
    console.log(hash); // 0x26db79c7c3c65992f17f4f62d5d191705933e785dff54db6d27e6f3a92d7117e
  } else {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

(3) call (execute get() method)

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://xxxx:xxxx"));

var result = web3.eth.call({
    to: "0x692a70d2e424a56d2c6c27aa97d1a86395877b3a",
    data: "0x6d4ce63c" // get()
});

console.log(result); // 0x => I expected 1
```

Comment: What does the contract return? I mean, the output is 0 right?

Comment: It seems you are not deploying correctly your contract. To deploy a contract you have to send your message to the null address, ie {to: null}, but your are sending your message to 0x692a70.. which is an external owned account.

Comment: @PaoloGuerra yes (3) call returned 0x

Comment: @Ismael I used browser-solidity to make bytecode. At that time, I pressed "copy address" on the view. I thought the address was needed to deploy. Okey, I will deploy again. Thank you.

Comment: Anyway I agree with Ismal, the contract seems not be deployed correctly; also consider to add "constant" to your get function:
 
function get() constant returns(int) {

    return num;

  }

Comment: @PaoloGuerra Thanks. I will add "constant"

Comment: Don't forget when you are done to answer this question so it can be mark as resolved later. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contract was never deployed. You're sending function calls to a non-contract address.

See this answer to your similar question: [Is it possible to see contract raw code from TxHash?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/21433/is-it-possible-to-see-contract-raw-code-from-txhash/21445#21445)