# Is it possible to see contract raw code from TxHash?

Tags: contract-development

I created a contract.

https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x74426948905cd6e70e8b9d64a660b3c179b7c8a224ca5cd0234842768eb501db

I can see the input Data in hex on etherscan. How can I decode from this? I want to see the raw contract or contract code so that I can confirm whether my contract is correct or not.

Comment: Are you sure that transaction is correct? Here is an example of a transaction to a contract in Etherscan.io: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x80cd49594608c648beec3b4b33d6861ca3df9278c62537d2c4c875cd6af2dfdd . The "to" is recognized as a contract. Note that you might have the correct transaction; I'm just shooting in the dark.

Comment: @lungj seems my contract transaction is wrong. I will deploy again. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: @lungj You answered on my question exactly. If you post your answer I wil accept it. (stack exchange community may want to it to close this question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transaction you point to did not create a contract (called `deploying`).

Did you use Mist or Parity wallet to 'deploy' the contract or did you simply send the byte data to an address via `geth` command line?

If you were trying to deploy the contract code, the `to` field would be `0x0`. Because `to` is not `0x0` but just a regular (non-contract) account, the byte data in the `input` field is simply ignored (although it can be interpreted as a message).

If `to` is not `0x0` you aren't deploying a contract. If the address was a contract, Etherscan would indicate as much.

Comment: Thank you. As you said, my deploying was wrong. I deploy with sendrawtransaction. At that time, I put the wrong value into "to" param. My deploying was described on another my question. https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/21428/contract-state-does-not-change-after-sendtransaction

Comment: Yes. A deployment will always be to `0x0`. You should select my answer so others are not confused.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that transaction is correct? [Here is an example](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x80cd49594608c648beec3b4b33d6861ca3df9278c62537d2c4c875cd6af2dfdd) of a transaction to a contract in Etherscan.io. The "to" is recognized as a contract. Note that you might have the correct transaction; I'm just shooting in the dark.

Comment: I don't understand why this answer was accepted. It doesn't answer the question. The trouble is that no contract was deployed as one can tell given that the `to` address is not a contract. I suspect the OP incorrectly sent byte code to an 'regular' address under the assumption that this was how one deploys a contract, which is not correct.

Comment: The example link was for sending to a contract (which contrasts with OP's sending to a regular address).

Comment: OP says "I create a contract" and then points to creation transaction. The `to` address of a deployment should be '0x0'. I read the OP's original post (and other posts by same author) as saying that he deployed with the referenced transaction. (Which he/she didn't.)  The same author posted this question (https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/21428/contract-state-does-not-change-after-sendtransaction/21446#21446) which has the same problem of no deployment.